# UTF-8 encoding converts strings to bytes with strange characters

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, encode

I'm using UTF-8 encoding to write my text data to a CSV file. But the csv document contains some really weird characters like,

```
\n\n#\xd9\x83\xd8\xb4\xd9\x85\xd9\x8a\xd8\xb1_\xd8\xaa\xd8\xb0\xd8\xa8\xd8\xad_\xd9\x88\xd9\x83\xd8\xaa\xd8\xa7\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa7_\xd8\xaa\xd8\xad\xd8\xaa\xd9\x81\xd9\x84 \n.
```

How do I fix this?

i changed

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

to

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding='utf-8').
```

it did not work.

My current code:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#pewdiepie-filter:retweets",count=5000, lang="en",tweet_mode="extended").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.full_text])
```

Thanks, Samuel Duraivel

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment string.

Use:

```
pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding='utf-8', comment="#")
```